# How to form an href in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

My menu links work fine on my local computer.  A typical one looks like this to get to the "About" page:

```
 <a class="link-text head-nav-home" href="About">
      <span class="text-link-text-2">About</span>
 </a>
```

Which translates to localhostxxx/About which in turn translates to localhostxxx/About/index

However, when I move the project to my hosting service I get to my home page just fine but when I try to navigate to the about page it can't find it.  The url is "myRootSite/About" where it should be "myRootSite/projectFolder/About".  If I change the href to "projectFolder/About" it still is not found as the url becomes "myRootSite/projectFolder/projectFolder/About"

My RouteConfig.cs is the standard MVC file and the url should just be created per

```
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Is there some way to reset or clear the url before each new navigation event.  Or have I missed something else?  Thanks

Comment: `href="@Url.Action("About")"`, or `@Html.ActionLink("Text inside a", "About")`

Comment: Thanks Mark, And I should have remembered that "~/About" works also.